# django project, iterate a list of data on each call of a function

Tags: django, list, loops

I have a django project in which for each user I will call a function. In this function, I have parameter, x_id = my_array[k]. I want to loop through the my_array on each call of the function.

I tested putting array data on a file and reading and using iter and next. But on each call it's doing the same and not looping. Any suggestion?

```
my_array = ['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'magenta', 'black', 'yellow', 'pink', 'green']

def my func():
   a = my_array[indx]
```

Like I said the goal is rotating my_array list on each call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the current index somewhere. A good place for this would be the session. So you could do:

```
current = request.session.get("current", -1)
index = current + 1
a = my_array[index]
request.session["current"] = index
```